# Sass error for loop with animation duration

Tags: sass

I am having an issue with a Sass loop. I want to make the animation `.1` seconds, `.2` seconds etc...Here is the loop:

```
@for $i from 1 through 6 {
  #elem span:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    animation-delay: .#{$i}s;
  }
}
```

The issue seems to be with the period here: `.#{$i}s`

If I remove it it works fine, but I get my animation in seconds and not fractions of a second as I would like it.

Comment: Why not make it `#{$i}00ms` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the `.#{$i}s` by quotes and then use [`unquote()`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#unquote-instance_method) string function to fix the issue, as follows:

```css
@for $i from 1 through 6 {
  #elem span:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    animation-delay: unquote(".#{$i}s");
  }
}
```

From the [doc](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#unquote-instance_method):

> `unquote($string)` Removes quotes from a string. If the string is
>   already unquoted, this will return it unmodified.

Comment: @Grinfax You are welcome. Seems you are new to Stackoverflow, If so, please consider *[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)*.